# add_shipping on wc_create_order (woo commerce)

Tags: woocommerce

I have successfully able to create an order through functions.php file.

I need help adding the free_shipping into the order. Can you please help with this one line?

The code I used to create an order on functions.php:

```
    $lp_order = wc_create_order();
    $lp_order->add_product( get_product( $lp_product_id ), 1 ); //(get_product with id and next is for quantity)
    $lp_order->set_address( $lp_address_full, 'billing' );
    $lp_order->set_address( $lp_address_full, 'shipping' );
    $lp_order->update_status('processing');
    $lp_order->add_shipping();
```

On the last line, what array should I pass to the add_shipping function? I tried using

$lp_order->add_shipping('free_shipping');

but it does not work.

Full code on functions.php

```
function lp_create_order() {

    $lp_email = $_POST["lp_email"];
    $lp_firstname = $_POST["lp_firstname"];
    $lp_lastname = $_POST["lp_lastname"];
    $lp_phone = $_POST["lp_phone"];
    $lp_address_1 = $_POST["lp_address_1"];
    $lp_address_2 = $_POST["lp_address_2"];
    $lp_city = $_POST["lp_city"];
    $lp_state = $_POST["lp_state"];
    $lp_postcode = $_POST["lp_postcode"];
    $lp_product_id = $_POST["lp_product_id"];


    if ( isset( $lp_product_id ) ) {

        $lp_address_full = array(
            'first_name' => $lp_firstname,
            'last_name'  => $lp_lastname,
            'company'    => '',
            'email'      => $lp_email,
            'phone'      => $lp_phone,
            'address_1'  => $lp_address_1,
            'address_2'  => $lp_address_2, 
            'city'       => $lp_city,
            'state'      => $lp_state,
            'postcode'   => $lp_postcode,
            'country'    => 'CA'
        );

        $lp_order = wc_create_order();
        $lp_order->add_product( get_product( $lp_product_id ), 1 ); //(get_product with id and next is for quantity)
        $lp_order->set_address( $lp_address_full, 'billing' );
        $lp_order->set_address( $lp_address_full, 'shipping' );
        $lp_order->update_status('processing');
        //$lp_order->add_shipping('free_shipping',0);      
        //$lp_order->calculate_shipping();
        $lp_order->calculate_totals();

        print "Order is placed";

    } // end if

} // end lp_create_order
add_action( 'init', 'lp_create_order' );
```

Answer (score 2):

For the order's add_shipping method, this is what i was able to successfully pass through on Woo-Commerce 2.6

```
$ship_rate_ob = new WC_Shipping_Rate();
$ship_rate_ob->id=0;
$ship_rate_ob->label='Free Shipping';
$ship_rate_ob->taxes=array(); //not required in your situation
$ship_rate_ob->cost=0; //not required in your situation
$lp_order->add_shipping($ship_rate_ob);
```

I am setting the shipping rate's id to 0. It is working for now but I would recommend setting it to an existing free_shipping rate in your database. You can find your shipping rate's ID in the url of it's edit page.

Answer (score 0):

`add_shipping()` expects `WC_Shipping_Rate` array, Use Woocommerce default free shipping package for this.

do some thing like this.

```
$lp_order->add_shipping(
   array (
        'id' => 'free_shipping',
        'label'    => "Free Shipping",
        'cost'     => 0.00,
        'taxes'    => array(),
        'calc_tax'  => 'per_order'
    )
);
```

Comment: I got this return: Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php on line 338

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the shipping:

```
$shippingAddress = array(
        'first_name' => $lp_firstname,
        'last_name'  => $lp_lastname,
        'company'    => '',
        'address_1'  => $lp_address_1,
        'address_2'  => $lp_address_2, 
        'city'       => $lp_city,
        'state'      => $lp_state,
        'postcode'   => $lp_postcode,
        'country'    => 'CA'
    );
```

Just remove email and Phone and you're good.